# Can't extract link from href

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am trying to extract the link from hyperlink within a spreadsheet I got from a client. I have no problem doing this when the formula format is as below.

```
=HYPERLINK("http://google.com","Buy now")
```

but unfortunately this spreadsheet has the text "Buy Now" which links to "http://google.com" but it does not have anything other than "Buy Now" in the formula bar, where I am expecting the "HYPERLINK" format.

The reason I ask is that I need to extract the URL from the HYPERLINK but can't use a function to do this as I don't know the location of the link.

Answer (score -1):

The answer for the above issue when using Microsoft Excel can be found here: http://howtouseexcel.net/how-to-extract-a-url-from-a-hyperlink-on-excel

The link above explains the following information on how to update the column using VBA script.

> 1. Open up a new workbook.
> 2. Get into VBA (Press Alt+F11)
> 3. Insert a new module (Insert > Module)
> 4. Copy and Paste the Excel user defined function below
> 5. Press F5 and click “Run”
> 6. Get out of VBA (Press Alt+Q)

---

> Excel user defined function
>
> ```
> Sub ExtractHL()
> Dim HL As Hyperlink
> For Each HL In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
> HL.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value = HL.Address
> Next
> End Sub
> ```

There is some more information on making these changes so it may be a good idea to check out the above link.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10811786)

Comment: Thank you for the heads up @NathanOliver I have edited the answer.